# If a UNIX system is shutdown and it is not coming up, how do I resolve the problem?

Tags: linux, aix

Let's say I have remotely logged into a UNIX system and I run reboot command.
The system shuts down but does not come up. What should I do now?

Comment: Are you taking a test? This is the second test-like question I've seen of yours.

Answer (score 3):

If the system is not booting fully, you will need to access it by logging into it directly. You need to get access to the physical machine (or VM server for a virtual machine) and log in from there.

Once you do that, you will have to figure out why it didn't boot properly and fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You should go to the console. Hopefully you have remote console capability, but if not, go there physically (or send someone there if it's in a remote data center).

Comment: The Console is where I login? Like I use putty to make the connection and login. Should I try logging in again then?

Comment: Given that question...  you should find a sysadmin who knows what he or she is about and ask them to solve the problem.